# Width of Action Bar in Google Tv Android

Tags: android, android-actionbar, google-tv

How change the ActionBar's Width in Google TV addon [Honeycomb 3.1]?

Answer (score 1):

There's an updated AddOn, that restores the ActionBar to the top - so it's now as wide as the screen.  We've released LeftNavBar sample code at http://code.google.com/p/googletv-android-samples/ (Click on Source)  You can use this code on a tablet.

That provides similar functionality to what we had before, and goes with our recommended UI Guidelines.  You can have your LNB on the left as hidden, minimized, or expanded, and expanded can be overlaid on your content or push it aside as needed by your app.

Check it out!

Comment: Is the expectation that developers will import the 'LeftNavBarLibrary' into projects and use that directly? Or is there something built into the GoogleTV-addon to replicate this library?

Comment: At the moment, the direction is to import the library into your project and use it directly.  Some developers will modify the library to suit their needs.